# jquery: image fade in on load

Tags: jquery

Right now, I have it so that when the user hovers over the box, the image fades out and the text/link gets revealed as shown in the jsfiddle below.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hrs2a/2/

I am trying to add on the ability to have the entire image fade in on load and have a loading gif display until the image is ready. I tried the following but it didn't work.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hrs2a/3/

Any idea on how I can get this to work? All help would be greatly appreciated. By the way, I asked a similar question in another thread but am opening this new question since I didn't ask the full scope of what I needed and what I did ask in that other thread got answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img').load(function() {
   $('loader').hide();
   $('img').show(5000);
});
```

You also need to initially hide the image and show the loader gif.

Comment: I've been trying to insert this code but I can't figure it out for the life of me. Any chance you can show me where to insert it?

Comment: I tried putting the code in but it's still not working. Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hrs2a/4/ Any chance you can take a look at it to see where I went wrong?